# sorting pandas dataframe with inf and NaN

Tags: sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that I would like to sort in descending order of a column.

```
Name   count
AAAA    -1.1
BBBB     0
CCCC    -10
DDDD     inf
EEEE     3
FFFF     NaN
GGGG     30
```

I want sort count in descending order and move `inf` and `NaN` rows to the end.
`df.sort('count',ascending = False,na_position="last")` pushes `NaN` to the end. How to deal with `inf`?

Answer (score 8):

You can treat inf values as null:

```
with pd.option_context('mode.use_inf_as_null', True):
    df = df.sort_values('count', ascending=False, na_position='last')


df
Out: 
   Name      count
6  GGGG  30.000000
4  EEEE   3.000000
1  BBBB   0.000000
0  AAAA  -1.100000
2  CCCC -10.000000
3  DDDD        inf
5  FFFF        NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

One of possible solutions:

```
In [33]: df.assign(x=df['count'].replace(np.inf, np.nan)) \
           .sort_values('x', ascending=False) \
           .drop('x', 1)
Out[33]:
   Name      count
6  GGGG  30.000000
4  EEEE   3.000000
1  BBBB   0.000000
0  AAAA  -1.100000
2  CCCC -10.000000
3  DDDD        inf
5  FFFF        NaN
```